# What form is this? おわってなさすぎ

Tags: て-form

> おわってなさすぎ

There's te-form for owarimasu, and I see sugiru form. What does the "nasasugi" part mean?

Comment: I suspect that it is related to http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6783/542

Comment: That looks correct, so what does that whole phrase mean?

Comment: I do not know. Can you provide the rest of the sentence for context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おわっていない = unfinished.

すぎる is a conjugation attached to the stem of a verb to mean "too much". However, when すぎる follows a negative form, ない becomes なさすぎる.

Therefore おわってなさすぎる would mean "__ is too unfinished", and おわってなさすぎ is its stem.

Comment: What do you mean by stem? The 連用形, or the invariant part? I'm asking because it is not uncommon to consider the 連体形 ("dictionary" form) the base form.

Comment: In all my experience with the term [verb stem](http://japanese.about.com/library/weekly/aa031101b.htm), it has always referred to the part that precedes the -ます of the polite form of a verb.

Comment: Yeah, that's the 連用形. 'Stem' is a bit of a difficult word to use in the context of Japanese, as there's multiple 'stems' for different uses. Really, 終わります is best segmented as owar-i-mas-u, with the true 'stem' being owar-;  the various 〇〇形 forms are stems + single-vowel suffixes (for godan verbs, at least).