# 人間は普通ここに来れんのになあ I Know it means Humans Cannot Come here usually

Tags: negation, potential-form, auxiliaries

人間は普通ここに来れんのになあ I Know it means Humans Cannot Come here usually.

but doesn't 来られます　Means can come Potential Form But 来れ Then ん Confuses me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is verb ending ない shortened to ん?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16226/is-verb-ending-%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-shortened-to-%e3%82%93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to check out the Denshi Jisho entry for [ん](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%93).

In this case, ん is an abbreviation of ぬ, which is a negative verb ending.

A good way to translate 来れん would be “can't come”.