# What is "られん" in "付き合ってられん"? I can't found it in dictionary?

Tags: grammar, meaning, contractions

Context:https://www.pixiv.net/en/artworks/81045594
The google translate split "付き合ってられん" to words as "付き合って られん" but it seem is not a regular word I can't understand what do "られん" meaning or find out explain in dictionaries(jisho.org and tangorin.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

付き合ってられん is colloquial and blunt variation of 付き合っていられない. You cannot find られん alone in dictionaries because it's part of a conjugation.

- **付き合う**: "to deal with it", "to keep talking with you" in this context
- **付き合っている**: to keep talking with you (progressive)
- **付き合っていられる**: to be able to keep talking with you (potential-progressive)
- **付き合っていられない**: not to be able to keep talking with you (negative-potential-progressive)
- **付き合ってられない**: not to be able to keep talking with you (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010))
- **付き合ってられん**: not to be able to keep talking with you (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/16226/5010))

So 付き合ってられん in this context means "I can't deal with this any more", "I've had enough", "I'm outta here", etc. (付き合う has other meanings, so the context is important.)