# Why does the い-adjective require -さ conversion to match ～そうです？

Tags: grammar, adjectives, suffixes

I'm doing an example JLPT test, and I came across a sentence which required a blank to fill in. The correct version (according to the answer sheet) of the sentence is:

少し事情を説明したほうが**よさそう**だ。

Now, another option, which seemed correct to me was:

少し事情を説明したほうが**よそう**だ。

Why is the 2nd form incorrect? I always thought I can just drop the い　and add そうです　to the stem. Why do I have to transform the adjective into noun here? Thanks for clearing that for me.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6782/1628

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right; い-adjectives (except for negative -ない endings) do *not* take a さ before そう.

いい is actually just irregular; it becomes よさそう. That's just the way it is.

Here's a complete list of conjugation rules for the -そう grammar pattern, quoted from [Tae Kim's Guide to Japanese](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/similarity):

> 1. Verbs must be changed to stem.
> 2. The 「い」in i-adjectives must be dropped except for 「いい」.
> 3. 「いい」must first be conjugated to「よさ」.
> 4. For all negatives, the 「い」must be replaced with 「さ」.
> 5. This grammar does not work with plain nouns.