# Grammar explanation for '...ことができなくなります'

Tags: grammar, negation, i-adjectives

Is 'できなく' converted from 'できない'?
I've learned adj. '..い' can convert to '..く' in this case.
Does verb's 'ない' form also have such transformation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does verb's 'ない' form also have such transformation?

Yes. ない behaves just like an i-adjective. And the continuative form is なく just as you'd expect.

As you may already know, to say 'becomes *adjective*' you replace the い of an i-adjective with く and the な of a na-adjective with に, then add なる.

So できる (can do) -> できない (unable to do) -> できなくなる (become unable to do).

Comment: `ない behaves just like an i-adjective` For the most part, but be careful with the ～そう conjugation for "seemingly not".  See answers on this question for details.  [Confusion about “Seemingly not ～”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1701/78).