# Word meaning and grammar help

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I encountered this in something I read:

彼らの頭髪は金髪や白髪、茶髪を始めとして緑髪から青髪まで様々で、さらに格好は鎧やら踊子風の衣装やら黒一色のローブやら『それ』らしすぎる。

1. Do the quotations around それ means that it is emphasized? If so, how does it work in this sentence?

2. I do not understand the らしすぎる. I am unable to find an answer online. However, I learnt that すぎる means "too much". If this is the intended meaning and not part of a figure of speech, what is it saying too much of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This それ refers to something along the lines of "***that*** typical fantasy elements we all know". If you're reading a Japanese light novel, this sentence means this character is seeing "that" typical fantasy or 異世界 world with monsters, wizards, elves and maybe adventurer's guilds. It's enclosed in quotes because the author wanted you to notice this implication. それらしい/[それっぽい](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%9D%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84) often means "typical looking" on its own.
- すぎる basically means "overly" or "too much" in standard Japanese, but this type of すぎる is just a humorous emphasis ("so much", "terribly", etc.). See: [What does できなさすぎる mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/66645/5010)