# Meaning of もはや本気すぎて逆にカワイイって言えなくなるアレだ

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm looking for some help understanding the second line in the below. The context is that Person 1 is showing pictures of girls to his friend, Person 2, who has just transferred to the school.

> Person 1「あぁ、東条さんな。この子はあれだ。ガチで好きな人ランキング圧倒的１位だ」
>
> Person 2「**もはや本気すぎて逆にカワイイって言えなくなるアレ**だな」
>
> Person 1「あぁ。……いいんだな。お前、刺されるかもしれないぞ」

In the first line, Person 1 says that she is 「ガチで好きな人ランキング圧倒的１位だ」- she is overwhelmingly #1 in the ranking of favourite / most liked people.

The third line implies that if he (Person 2) approaches this girl he's going to get a hard time from other boys (get stabbed) since she is the most popular.

Line 2 however is a bit unclear. Does 本気すぎて refer to the people who voted for her, and カワイイって言えなくなる refer to those same people?

Comment: The context is a little vague. It'd help if you could give [more details](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important), such as the name of the source material. For instance, does person 2 know 東条さん?

Comment: No person 2 didnt know of 東条さん until person 1 showed them a picture.

Comment: What are they doing? Person 2 has just chosen a girl? For what? And is this "ranking" the result of a real vote that took place in the past?

Comment: They are currently in Person 2's room and Person 1 is showing him pictures of what he has identified as the top 4 girls in the school. Person 2 had pointed at the picture of 東条さん to ask for more information about her. From the readers point of view it isn't clear whether this ranking is the result of a real vote or Person 1's opinion, although we do find out she is very popular a little later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in this context, they are **not** talking about certain boys who are serious or crazy about 東城さん, right? Then this 本気すぎて just means 本気でカワイすぎて, which is roughly the same as ガチでカワイすぎて. Person 2 is saying her attractiveness is so extreme that he hesitate to use a common and casual compliment such as 可愛い.

Comment: Ah thanks for this makes more sense now. I did google before your answer and see many utterances of something to that effect "i.e. when people see things that are truly cute, they are unable to say that" but I didn't imagine that カワイイ was dropped so I was a bit confused as to what  本気すぎて was referring to.

Comment: @fearless Yes people [overuse 過ぎる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66651/5010) these days :)